# Finding the index of the columns in a dataset which has a particular values

Tags: loops, sas

I have a table in which rows are an identifier, and columns are flag as shown below.

```
ID  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10
17028   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
17030   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
17037   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
17040   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
17041   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
```

For each row, i want a flag which represents the concatenated names or indexes of the variable with value = 1.

This is the code that i used, but seems a little in-efficient though gets the job done.

```
data temp71;
set temp7;
format flag 20.;
flag=0;
if c1= 1 then flag=flag+1000000000000000;
if c2= 1 then flag=flag+100000000000000;
if c3= 1 then flag=flag+10000000000000;
if c4= 1 then flag=flag+1000000000000;
if c5= 1 then flag=flag+100000000000;
if c6= 1 then flag=flag+10000000000;
if c7= 1 then flag=flag+1000000000;
if c8= 1 then flag=flag+100000000;
if c9= 1 then flag=flag+10000000;
if c10= 1 then flag=flag+1000000;
if c11= 1 then flag=flag+100000;
if c12= 1 then flag=flag+10000;
if c13= 1 then flag=flag+1000;
if c14= 1 then flag=flag+100;
if c15= 1 then flag=flag+10;
if c16= 1 then flag=flag+1;
run;
```

Comment: @Tom I have included my code which i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using a character variable instead of a number.  If you use a character variable then you can hold 32,767 flags.

```
flagc = cats(of c1-c10);
```

If you try to do what you did using base 10 then you can only hold 15 flags in one number. If you used base 2 you could hold 53 flags.

```
%let nvars=10;
data want ;
  set have ;
  length flagc $&nvars flag2 flag10 8;
  format flag2 binary&nvars.. flag10 z&nvars..;
  flagc = cats(of c1-c&nvars);
  flag10 = input(flagc,&nvars..);
  flag2  = input(flagc,binary&nvars..);
  put id (c1-c&nvars) (1.) +1 flag2 flag10 flagc ;
run;

17028 0100010010 0100010010 0100010010 0100010010
17030 1110100010 1110100010 1110100010 1110100010
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CAT function to concatenate all the variables together, one line of code will generate your flag variable.

```
flag = catt(of c1--c10);
```

However, you've also indicated that you might want the names of the variables so you can also use a catx function to concatenate the names together. Here's a sample of how that might work:

```
data have;
input ID $  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10;
cards;
17028   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
17030   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
17037   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
17040   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
17041   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
;
run;


data want;

set have;
array c(10) c1-c10;

flag = catt(of c1--c10);

length names $50.;

do i=1 to dim(c);
if c(i)=1 then names=catx(", ", names, vname(c(i)));
end;
run;
```

Comment: @Reeze: It works, thanks a lot. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This solution was posted before your edit and offers a different result than the one you previously attempted.

```
data have;
  input ID $  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10;
  datalines;
17028   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
17030   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
17037   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
17040   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
17041   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
;

data want(drop=i);
  set have;
  array C(10);
  format flag $20.;
  do i = 1 to 10;
    if C(i) = 1 then flag = catx(",",flag,put(i,1.));
  end;
run;

proc print data=want;
  var flag;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs flag 
1   2,6,9 
2   1,2,3,5,9 
3   2,8,9 
4   1,2,5,9 
5   2,7,9
```